# How to filter an array of objects based on ID?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, javascript-objects

I have the following array of objects, I want to loop through it and filter based on the id or code that I pass into the function.

```
state.products = [{id = 1, name = Bottle},{id = 2, name = umbrella}, {id = 3, name = shoe}]

const getVal = (id)=> {

 const av = state.products.filter((s) s.productId == id)

}
```

The following doesn't seem to iterate through the array and check through each object? I am getting an empty array for console.log(av)

Comment: `state.products.filter((s) => s.id == id)`

Answer (score 2):

You are on a right way, but you are not using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) properly.

And also the provided array of object is not also in a good format. Object should be in a `key:value` pairs.

```js
state.products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Bottle" },
    { id: 2, name: "umbrella" },
    { id: 3, name: "shoe" }
]

const getAllArrayExcept = (id) => {
    // this will return all the array except provided id
    return state.products.filter((s) => s.id !== id)
}

const getOnlyArray = (id) => {
    // this will return only item which match the provided id
    return state.products.filter((s) => s.id === id)
}

console.log(getAllArrayExcept(1))
/*
output: [{ id = 2, name = umbrella }, { id = 3, name = shoe }]
*/
console.log(getOnlyArray(1))
/*
output: [{ id = 1, name = Bottle }]
*/
```

Here is the working snippet:

```js
const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Bottle" },
    { id: 2, name: "umbrella" },
    { id: 3, name: "shoe" }
]

const getAllArrayExcept = (id) => {
    // this will return all the array except provided id
    return products.filter((s) => s.id !== id)
}

const getOnlyArray = (id) => {
    // this will return only item which match the provided id
    return products.filter((s) => s.id === id)
}

console.log("All array except: ", getAllArrayExcept(1))
console.log("Only provided item in array: ", getOnlyArray(1))
```